# Python program to remove all special characters from a folder and its subfolders' and files' names

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, file-rename

I need a python program that can take a folder and and all folders within it (including all files in those folders) and remove all special characters from its name. I have this but fear I am going in the wrong direction. (Yes I know the special character library I have isn't complete)

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

path = Path("C:/Users/Connor/OneDrive - Adsero IP, LLC/Desktop/Specs/€2/3€")
bad_chars = ['â', '€']
os.chdir(path)
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in bad_chars, file))))

for dir, subdir, folder in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for folder in path:
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir, folder), os.path.join(dir, "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in bad_chars, folder))))
```

I've tried messing around with this a lot but want others ideas an opinions before I spend a lot more time trying to brute force it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your code to be something like the example below;

In your code you have assigned the same variable 'folder' twice, first as an 'os.walk' variable then as a variable for 'path'.

```
for dir, subdir, folder in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for folder in path:
```

Also not a good thing to use variables that match python reserved words like 'dir'.
I dont think its necessary to do two walks for directories and files.
You'd also want topdown to be False so directory names are changed from bottom up. 'Top down' will rename directories above those yet to be updated and break the path meaning lower level directories won't be renamed.

```
root = "C:/Users/Connor/OneDrive - Adsero IP, LLC/Desktop/Specs/€2/3€"
bad_chars = ['â', '€']
os.chdir(root)
for path, subdir, files in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
    for folder in subdir:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, folder),
                  os.path.join(path, "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in bad_chars, folder))))
    for file in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file),
                  os.path.join(path, "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in bad_chars, file))))
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) [file-rename](/questions/tagged/file-rename)